# Multivariate inequality

Tags: inequality, convex-geometry

I am tring to prove that:

$K = 2$:

$$ \sum_{i < j} p_i \cdot p_j \leq {N \choose 2}(\frac 1N \sum_{i} p_i)^2$$

$K = 3$:

$$ \sum_{i < j < m} p_i \cdot p_j \cdot p_m \leq {N \choose 3}(\frac 1N \sum_{i} p_i)^3$$

where $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$ for $i=1..N$

I simulate these and it seems to be correct even for larger $K$'s.

I think that proving the concavity of the function $\sum_{i \ne j} p_i \cdot p_j$ and $\sum_{i \ne j \ne m} p_i \cdot p_j \cdot p_m$ suffice and computed the hessian but don't see a way to prove it semi-negative.

I checked and the function is not concave.

Comment: I take it $i$ and $j$ run from $1$ to $N$ (but this should appear explicitly in the body of the question). The statements can't be true with strict inequality, since one has equality if all the $p_i$ are equal.

Comment: Obviously I meant inequality and not strict inequality

Comment: I think I am able to prove this but the proof is not pretty. Taking 2 variables and fixing all the rest, adding eps to the smaller one and subtracting eps from the big one increase the function value. I’ll write it fully later but there should be a better way to prove this

Comment: I think that's a fine proof.

Comment: Wait – are you sure you want $\sum_{i\ne j}$, and not $\sum_{i<j}$? Take $N=2$; the left side is $p_1p_2+p_2p_1=2p_1p_2$. Take $p_1=p_2=p$, the left side is $2p^2$, the right side is $p^2$, the inequality fails.

Comment: you are right and i fixed the quastion

Comment: Three answers have been posted, nir. Any thoughts about any of them?

Comment: The first answer seems to be full, and uses the idea mention before but I hoped for a nicer proof. The second proof, works only for $K=2$ while the last one (mine :)) is nice but not complete since i haven't prove the final statment which i don't see how to do that. 

I can accross the Poisson binomial distribution which is the standard name for this distribution and there is a theorem by hoffding that prove that in some cases the inequality also hold in probability and not just the upper bound but it doesn't hold every where

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to prove the $K=2$ inequality.

I'm going to define $A,B,C$ by
$$
A=\sum_{i<j}p_ip_j,\qquad B=\sum_ip_i^2,\qquad C=\sum_{i<j}(p_i-p_j)^2. 
$$
Note that
$$
\bigl(\sum_ip_i\bigr)^2=2A+B,\qquad C\ge0,\qquad C=(N-1)B-2A
$$
We are trying to prove
$$
A\le{N\choose2}\biggl({1\over N}\sum_ip_i\biggr)^2={N-1\over2N}(2A+B)
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
2NA\le2(N-1)A+(N-1)B
$$
which is equivalent to $2A\le(N-1)B$, which follows immediately from $C\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Fact 1.** Let $p_i \ge 0, i = 1, 2, \cdots, N$ ($N \ge 2$). Let $1\le k \le N$. Prove that
$$\sum_{i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k} p_{i_1} p_{i_2} \cdots p_{i_k} 
\le \binom{N}{k}\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N p_i\right)^k.$$

**Proof of Fact 1.**

If $k = 1$, it is clear. In the following, assume that $k \ge 2$.

Let $Q > 0$ be an arbitrary constant. Consider the maximum of
$f(p) := \sum_{i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k} p_{i_1} p_{i_2} \cdots p_{i_k} $
subject to $\sum_{i=1}^N p_i = Q$ and $p_i \ge 0, i = 1, \cdots, N$.
Clearly, the maximum is positive.

We claim that at maximum, all $p_i$'s are equal.
Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that
at maximum, there exist $r < s$ such that $p_r \ne p_s$.
Note that
$$\sum_{i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k} p_{i_1} p_{i_2} \cdots p_{i_k}
= A p_r p_s + B(p_r + p_s) + C$$
where all $A, B, C$ do not contain $p_r, p_s$.
If $A = 0$, then $\sum_{i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k} p_{i_1} p_{i_2} \cdots p_{i_k} = 0$
which contradicts the positivity of the maximum.
If $A > 0$, we have
$$A p_r p_s + B(p_r + p_s) + C
< A (p_r + p_s)^2/4 + B(p_r + p_s) + C$$
and thus, if we replace $p_r, p_s$ with
$\frac12(p_r + p_s), \frac12(p_r + p_s)$,
we get a larger objective value,
which contradicts the optimality of $p$.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_0(x_1,...,x_N) = 1$ and:
$$f_k(x_1,...,x_N) = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\cdot f_{k-1}(x_1,.\hat{x}_i,..,x_N) $$

where $\hat{x}_i$ means that $x_i$ does not apper.

The claim is proved if we will show that $f_k(x_1,...,x_N)$ is maximized on $f_k(\alpha,...,\alpha)$ for a fixed $\alpha$ where the maximization is done on vector $\vec{x}$ such that $\sum_i x_i = C$.

We use lagrange multipliers:

Let $$L(\vec{x},\lambda) = f_k(\vec{x}) + \lambda\cdot(\sum_i x_i - C)$$

$\frac{dL}{dx_i} = f_{k-1}(x_1,.\hat{x}_i,..,x_N) - \lambda\cdot C$

Thus: $f_{k-1}(x_1,.\hat{x}_i,..,x_N) = C'$ and from this and the symmetry it follow that $x_i=\alpha$ for all $i$.